# Dynamically Change onSeries property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Say I have 3 series with ids `series1`, `series2` and `flags`. Initially `flags` has its `onSeries` property set to `series1`.  When I click on the legend to hide `series1`, is there a way in that `legendItemClick` event to dynamically set the `onSeries` property of `flags` to `series2`?  I can't seem to find a method of doing so.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update flags series via [Series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update) and change `onSeries` property.

```
legendItemClick: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent toggle visibility
      this.chart.get('flags-series').update({ // get the flag series and update it
        onSeries: this.options.id
      });
    }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/pfx77nn4/